# java： how to obfuscate the account information in my application?

Tags: java

There is a function that can keep the users' account information in my application.I wanna keep it safely.How can I obfuscate the information ?And how to decode it rightly when I wanna use?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Define "account information", "keep it", and "obfuscate". There's too much room for interpretation right now.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you are looking for is encryption not obfuscation. This [article](http://wikijava.org/wiki/Secret_Key_Cryptography_Tutorial) seems to explain the basics. Stackoverflow has [lots about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/encryption+java) it as well. Also have a look at related tags like cryptography